# Tomcat BASIC Auth without web.xml modification

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there any possibility to add container basic auth without changing application web.xml, which is located inside war file? Maybe I can add something in ${catalina_home}/conf/Catalina/localhost/.xml

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to declare the BasicAuthenticator in your context.xml but it will require some underlying realm which appropriate roles.